# Owin overrides authentication on IIS client certificate mapping rule

Tags: iis, owin

I have configured a WebAPI web site to use HTTPS with IIS Client Certificate Mapping(ManyToOneMapping ) for client certificate authentication. I disabled all Authentication types on IIS. I did many to one configuration on IIS.

But it is working with any other certificate which added to server's trusted store. I found that it is because of the Owin. I'm using owin(bearer authentication) to manage the token etc. But I think owin overrides the iis many to one configuration. Do you know how to disable it? I need token based authentication so I can not remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Owin to self-host WebAPI and hosting WebAPI in IIS are two different hosting models. This means that all of Owin's pipeline logic is no longer valid. Unless we're using Owin hosting in a self-hosting program, here's a simple example of using Owin self-hosting WebAPI.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

If we want to verify the client certificate by OWIN middleware(a pipe in which a request must come by), we should add a custom validator of the client certificate and apply it by using `appBuilder.Use<T>` method.

```
appBuilder.Use<ClientCertificateAuthMiddleware>(new ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions(), clientCertificateValidator);
```

Here is an example of how to add a validation client certificate to the OWIN self-hosted WebApi.
https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/02/08/using-client-certificates-in-net-part-9-working-with-client-certificates-in-owinkatana-iii/
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.